# Как реализовать поиск по массиву сообщений ? React,Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Массив сообщений хранится в отдельном редьюсере, состоит из полей id,photo, text, clientName. Как реализовать поиск, который будет реагировать на onChange инпута основной формы, и выводить сообщения, текст которых совпадает с текущем значением input?

Answer (score 0):

Можно в редьюсере создать ещё одно состояние типа

```
const initialState = {
    array: [some data],
    arrayWithSearch: []
};
```

затем организовать action типа

```
const someReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_ARRAY_WITH_SEARCH:
            return {
                ...state,
                arrayWithSearch: array.fiter((element) => {
                      Тут логика отбора и заполнения массива  учитывая по какому 
                      параметру идёт поиск (action.значение поиска)
                });
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

каждый раз на onChange вызывать этот action
и, собстна, отрисовывать этот массив с поиском.

Если я где-то неправ - говорите

Comment: Можно ведь прям в селекторе отфильтровать пробрасывая дополнительные парамтры, зачем создавать ещё один массив для этого?